# Is it safe to remove the caret in package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I sometimes want to switch my projects to use exact package versions.

Current:

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase": "^9.6.2",
  "next": "12.0.7",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  "react-firebase-hooks": "^4.0.2",
  "react-firebaseui": "^6.0.0"
}
```

Is it safe to simply **remove the carets** in front of the package names?

Or do I need to first *uninstall* these packages and *reinstall* specifying the exact version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look for the installed version with `npm list`, then fix that version in the package.json. That way you won't be changing any versions.